# Codeigniter join gives last id back

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I want to have the id from my table 'device_id' but I keep getting the id from 'inventory' because it is the last join.

I have tried to look it up on the internet but could found a solution for Codeigniter.

```
$this->db->where('device_id', $this->input->get('device_id'));

$this->db->join('repair_components', 'repair_options.component_id = repair_components.id');

$this->db->join('products', 'repair_options.product_id = products.id');

$this->db->join('inventory', 'repair_options.product_id = inventory.product_id', 'left');

$query = $this->db->get('repair_options');
$this->data['options'] = $query->result();

print_r($this->data['options']);
```

I want the id from 'device_id' in my array '$this->data['options']'.

Comment: What is the error/issue?

Comment: The problem has nothing to do with joins. You don't actually ask for any columns from a table named 'device_id'. It would be easier to help if the structure of the tables was known.

Answer (score 0):

Give **table name** to column in **where** clause and also make sure `$this->input->get('device_id')` have value in it.

```
$this->db->join('repair_components', 'repair_options.component_id = repair_components.id');
$this->db->join('products', 'repair_options.product_id = products.id');
$this->db->join('inventory', 'repair_options.product_id = inventory.product_id', 'left');
$this->db->where('table_name.device_id', $this->input->get('device_id'));
$query = $this->db->get('repair_options');
$this->data['options'] = $query->result();

print_r($this->data['options']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple but tricky one. all you need to do some changes..

```
$this->db->select('*,device_id.id as the_device_id');
$this->db->from('repair_options');
$this->db->where('device_id', $this->input->get('device_id'));

$this->db->join('repair_components', 'repair_options.component_id = repair_components.id');

$this->db->join('products', 'repair_options.product_id = products.id');

$this->db->join('inventory', 'repair_options.product_id = inventory.product_id', 'left');

$query = $this->db->get();
$this->data['options'] = $query->result();

print_r($this->data['options']);
```